# Unit Testing Method with Moq where Collection = serivce.GetCollection()?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, unit-testing, moq

New to unit testing & Moq. I have a WPF client app which hooks into a WCF service via `HttpBinding`. I have a test class in MSTest and I'm mocking my service with Moq like so:

```
 [TestClass]
public class ArticleDataGridTests
{
    //Mock channel for WCF service. Moq mocking framework.
    Mock<IIsesServiceChannel> channelMock = new Mock<IIsesServiceChannel>();  


    [TestMethod]
    public void LoadArticleTitlesListTestValid()
    {
        channelMock.Setup(c => c.GetArticleTitles());

        ArticleDataGridViewModel articleDataGridViewModel = new ArticleDataGridViewModel(channelMock.Object);
        articleDataGridViewModel.LoadArticleTitlesList();

        channelMock.Verify(c => c.GetArticleTitles(), Times.Once());
    }
}
```

}

Here is the method `LoadArticleTitles list` that's being invoked in the ViewModel. `ArticlesTitleList` is a `List<string>`:

```
   public void LoadArticleTitlesList()
    {
        ArticleTitlesList = new List<string>(IsesService.GetArticleTitles());
    }
```

Obviously this test fails. I get a null exception on the 'collection'. How do I mock this list of strings for my test or should I not be writing void method stubs with WCF service method calls which return lists nested inside them in the first place? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return data after setup:

```
var listOfStrings = new List<string>{{"test1"}};
channelMock.Setup(c => c.GetArticleTitles()).Returns(listOfStrings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to pass in an array of string rather than a `List<string>`  as WCF looks like a method that returns a `.ToList()` is stubbed out as returning an `[]string` in the boiler plate code. Therefore passing in a list of string gives an overloaded method invalid argument exception. Ended up with this:

```
 var ArticleTitlesList = new string[] { "LoadArticleTitlesListTestValid" };
 channelMock.Setup(c => c.GetArticleTitles()).Returns(ArticleTitlesList);
```

Comment: You can actually change this to return a List<string> in the WCF configuration settings.